# How do I fix the key error 0 in Geocoder with python

Tags: python, pandas, keyerror, geocoder

I am trying to map out the latitude and longitude from a column of addresses from a data frame. But it keeps giving me key error 0.

```
for i in range(len(df['addresses'])):
    g = geocoder.arcgis(df['addresses'][i])
    coordinates.append(tuple(g.latlng))
```

Here is the error message

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-43-8a4466f30728> in <module>
      1 coordinates = []
      2 for i in range(len(df['addresses'])):
----> 3     g = geocoder.arcgis(df['addresses'][i])
      4     coordinates.append(tuple(g.latlng))

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/series.py in __getitem__(self, key)
   1069         key = com.apply_if_callable(key, self)
   1070         try:
-> 1071             result = self.index.get_value(self, key)
   1072 
   1073             if not is_scalar(result):

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py in get_value(self, series, key)
   4728         k = self._convert_scalar_indexer(k, kind="getitem")
   4729         try:
-> 4730             return self._engine.get_value(s, k, tz=getattr(series.dtype, "tz", None))
   4731         except KeyError as e1:
   4732             if len(self) > 0 and (self.holds_integer() or self.is_boolean()):

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_value()

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_value()

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.Int64HashTable.get_item()

pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.Int64HashTable.get_item()

KeyError: 0
```

Comment: Can you copy in the entire error message?

Comment: I edited it. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer has been edited after getting more information from the OP.

I'm assuming that `df` is a Pandas dataframe.

The problem here is that `for i in range(len(df['addresses'])):` gives you an integer on every loop. You're then trying to get a list from the Pandas dataframe with that integer, which leads to a `KeyError`.

Take out the `range` and `len` from the for loop, and you'll get an address from the `addresses` column. Then pass that address to `geocoder`.

So, as follows:

```py
for address in df['addresses']:
    g = geocoder.arcgis(address)
```

[Documentation of Pandas dataframes](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html)

Comment: hmmm, interesting. but the column is not a dictionary.  could you explain it more?

Comment: it returns error TypeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object is not callable

Comment: Oh right, I totally missed that we're looking at pandas dataframes here. Hmm, what about taking just `for i in df['addresses']` ?

Comment: no still doesn't work. it just return 'KeyError: '3315 spenard road, anchorage'

Comment: Did you remove the `[i]` from row 3?
`for address in df['addresses']: 
    g = geocoder.arcgis(address)`

Comment: Great, I'll update my answer. Please consider accepting it.